# Looping through and displaying a list of images with the Image Cropper document type (Umbraco 7)

Tags: c#, html, image, razor, umbraco

I currently in the midst of changing my multiple media picker document type to 10 image cropper document types instead.

I'm unsure how to go about looping through these newly created properties and displaying them in my carousel element.

Before I used this code to loop through me media files:

```
@{var images = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("sommerhusSlideshowBilleder").ToList()};
@for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="@(i < 1 ? " active":"") item" data-slide-number="@i">
    <img src='@images[i].Url'>
  </div>
}
```

Now I instead need to loop through X number of "image cropper" images, which each has their own alias. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Though i haven't tried that but I think given can solve your problem or atleast give you a headstart or something.

Assuming "sommerhusSlideshowBilleder" is the alias of '10 image cropper',and img1..img10 are their respective aliases which may or may not be identical. since each image has their own id.

```
    var imageList = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Descendants("sommerhusSlideshowBilleder");
    if(@imageList.Count()>0){
    foreach(var image_alias in imageList)
    {@*to get url of image *@
   <img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.Content, propertyAlias: image_alias, height: 300, width: 400)" />

    }}
```

Do tell me how it goes.